# AHK is repeating itself

Tags: autohotkey

AHK not working properly. All are repeating themselves when I add a period then 
space bar (or any end character and space bar). i.e.

```
::fr::fragment
```

When I type "fr period space bar " this is what results: fragmenfragment

When I type "fr space bar of", it works properly: fragment of

Something with my keyboard? Was fine yesterday. (I'm not computer savvy, apology in advance if this is elementary.) Thanks!

Comment: Any code above or below that line? The code works fine for me.

Comment: same here, sample code works, so you should try a script with only that line and if that works, copy more lines from your original script to find out what causes the problem.

Comment: The hotstring might be triggering itself. Does the same issue happen with `::fr::testing`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be running two instances of your script.  You can try adding

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#Persistent
```

to the top of your script and then kill any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you're not running two instances of the same script.

You can kill the processes and try again - but this piece of code should work.

Try looking at SingleInstance in the future :)